# J’ai travaillé « en qualité DE rédacteur » ou « en qualité DU rédacteur » ?

Tags: articles, absence-d-article

Comme la question le présente – est-ce que l’on peut se servir de la forme « du » ici si c’était un poste concret ?

Que faire avec « en qualité de (l’)expert en quelque-chose » – la même règle serait-t-elle appliquée ? Dans ce dernier cas, je ne suis pas sûr que « de_expert » sonne bien.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non, ***en qualité*** impose ***de***.

> J'ai travaillé en qualité de rédacteur.
>
> J'ai travaillé en qualité d'expert en informatique de gestion.

On rencontrera plus souvent l''expression équivalente :

> J'ai travaillé en tant que rédacteur.

ou

> J'ai travaillé comme rédacteur.

L'article est aussi exclu dans ces expressions :

> <s>J'ai travaillé en tant que le rédacteur</s>

ou alors, le sens est différent (*comme le* signifiant *de la même façon que*):

> J'ai travaillé comme le rédacteur qui m'a précédé.

*Qualité du rédacteur* est possible dans d'autres contextes où qualité signifie aspects positifs de la personne occupant le poste, pas le fait qu'il soit un rédacteur :

> La principale qualité du rédacteur de ce projet est son style inimitable.

Answer (score 1):

Il faut dire « en qualité **de** rédacteur », jamais « en qualité du rédacteur ». De même on dit « en qualité d'expert » ; on ne trouve pas « en qualité de l'expert » ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=en+qualit%C3%A9+de+l%27expert%2Cen+qualit%C3%A9+d%27expert&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cen%20qualit%C3%A9%20d%27%20expert%3B%2Cc0)).

- Il a ordonné une vérification et a déclaré qu'en qualité d'expert comptable il se devait de le faire.
- En  qualité d'expert des infrastructures elle donne des avis sur ces problèmes.

Cependant on dit « en tant que le rédacteur », « en tant que l'expert » mais d'autre possibilités selon le contexte sont souvent utiles (« en tant qu'un rédacteur », « en tant qu'un expert »,« en tant que rédacteur », « en tant qu'expert »).

Comment: Hmm: " en tant que **le** rédacteur " ou "**qu'un** rédacteur"  ?

Comment: @jlliagre En y réfléchissant de nouveau cela pourrait être très marginal sinon pas utilisé. Il n'y a pas de problème avec les formes telles que « en tant qu'un **des** invités », en tant qu'un **des** ingénieurs », etc. Donc, « en tant qu'un invité », « en tant qu'un ingénieur » ne peuvent pas être exclus. Cependant, maintenant qu'il est souligné comme douteux, le cas avec « le » me parait bien moins certain ; il me semble ne pas m'en rappeler.

Comment: @user17522 1/ You might have to come to grip with the fact that when you ask two persons what's the first letter in the alphabet they'd better tell you both it's a. 2/ If you were as perspicacious in the case of other people'answers as you pretend to be in mine you'd notice that there is no end of the instances of questions in which several of the answers have a common content, that being the very consequence of "1/". 3/ Coming now to the case of the present question, let me tell your Sherlock Holmes that 9:01:17-8:46:55 is 14 minutes; (champ 1)

Comment: @user17522  you have to read the answer first and that's a good 3 to four minutes; there is then an ngram to get, which does not take less than one minute not counting the time that's needed in order to think about what to search for in the ngram, at least another minute; that's already 5 minutes; there are then two complicated examples to make up and I give you very conservatively 2 minutes for that (7); next there are several forms about which to make a decision as to their validity;those ideas do not pop into your mind just as does fancying having a cup of coffee; (champ 2)

Comment: @user17522 that's at the very least 3 more minutes (10);  there is at the most 5  minutes left to **think**, **write** and **correct** most of a 94 word text with 20 quote marks that have to be coded in ascii code. 4/ Besides those points I have to tell you that I don't fail to see that your wild allegations  are in keeping with your bizarre and relentless behaviour in the way of harassing me now and again since the first days I started working in the FSE 8 months ago, days when  you would rudely advise me to quit the FSE and choose another occupation. (end)

Comment: @user17522 PS Do you really think I've acquired an 11 k reputation in eight months plundering other people's answers?